# Glonass BN-808 Glonass BN-808 USB GPS Receiver Receiver in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, gps

I have installed OpenCPN in 18.04 and I bought a Glonass BN-808 USB GPS Receiver. It is apparently UBLOX M8030 although  I'm not sure what that actually means, but it is supposed to be supported in Linux.
However while *lsusb* can see the receiver at bus 001 device 003 ( which is nothing like the tty or /dev format requested by OpenCPN ), Ubuntu cannot read any data from said receiver.
I have followed the instructions in the OpenCPN manual but with no success.
Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks  Dave

**EDIT 1**: Output for tail -f /var/log/syslog

I ran tail -f /var/log/syslog and got a much larger output than you did, none of which made any sense to me.
The ublox receiver was detectedbut from there the output read:

```
May 23 15:34:19 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 kernel: [ 1018.870051] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=01a8 
May 23 15:34:19 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 kernel: [ 1018.870060] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
May 23 15:34:19 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 kernel: [ 1018.870064] usb 1-1.1: Product: u-blox GNSS receiver 
May 23 15:34:19 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 kernel: [ 1018.870068] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1" 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 kernel: [ 1019.001058] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 kernel: [ 1019.001512] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 kernel: [ 1019.001513] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 upowerd[1059]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 upowerd[1059]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 
May 23 15:34:20 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 upowerd[1059]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 
May 23 15:34:31 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 ModemManager[831]: [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1] creating modem with plugin 'u-blox' and '1' ports 
May 23 15:34:31 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 ModemManager[831]: Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyACM0', unhandled serial type' 
May 23 15:34:31 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 ModemManager[831]: Couldn't create modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1': Failed to find primary AT port 
May 23 15:42:58 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 systemd-resolved[770]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server fe80::8e0d:76ff:fe57:2816%3. 
May 23 15:48:17 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 systemd-resolved[770]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server 192.168.1.1. 
May 23 15:48:19 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 systemd-resolved[770]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server fe80::8e0d:76ff:fe57:2816%3. 
May 23 15:50:31 dave-Aspire-ES1-523 systemd-resolved[770]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.1.1.
```

I ran apt-get install gpsd-clients earlier but I’m not sure if it loaded correctly, I did see the word “fail” a few times.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to ensure that it is detected is to check `/var/log/syslog` on its connection:

1. Disconnect GNSS receiver
2. Open terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` command
3. Connect GNSS receiver and wait for its initialization

For my u-blox7 GPS/GLONASS I have the following output:

> May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.380440] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.509111] **usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=01a7**
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.509115] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.509117] **usb 3-2: Product: u-blox 7 - GPS/GNSS Receiver**
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.509119] **usb 3-2: Manufacturer: u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com**
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.509363] usb 3-2: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 12 was not an MTP device
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.537420] **cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device**
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.538041] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
>   May 22 23:50:08 hostname kernel: [99544.538044] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters

Note the bold lines above - we see that it is really **u-blox 7** and that it is recognized as serial port - **ttyACM0** (really `/dev/ttyACM0`).

To test the GNSS receiver you can use `gpsmon` (it will decode NMEA to time, latitude, longitude and other data):

1. Install `gpsmon` with `sudo apt-get install gpsd-clients`
2. Launch `gpsmon` for the found serial port with `sudo gpsmon /dev/ttyACM0`
3. Wait GNSS to find satellites and get NMEA data.

---

Note: to have access to serial ports as normal user, you need to add your user to the `dialout` group with `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel is not handling the type correctly.

Create a file: /etc/udev/rules.d/49-ublox.rules
Say by the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/49-ublox.rules
```

and put the following text into it:

```
# 1546:01a8 - uBlox Receiver
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a8", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a8", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a8", MODE:="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a8", MODE:="0666"
```

Then either restart or write:

```
 sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

After which plug the device again. The device should show up as /dev/ttyACM0 (the number might change). Then you can continue from the previous answers.

Comment: Where do I put this file?

Comment: @Dave.Jumanji The name of the file is 49-ublox.rules, and put it in the /etc/udev/rules.d/  directory. (You will need to be root to do so).

Comment: Thanks but I'm way out of my depth here. I don't know how to do that and searching this site generates answers I don't understand.

Comment: Do not panic! It really works after all... :-) It is mostly harmless!