# What's wrong with my usb/gpsmon?

Tags: usb, gps

I got a mini usb GPS receiver to work... apparently... but the lat/lon is not even a possible value and I am not sure if this is a calculation issue or a hardware issue. This is the first I have tried one of these usb receivers. Is this one a dud or do I just need to install a gps almanac or something, where I missed a step?

```bsh
$ sudo gpsmon /dev/ttyACM0
```

```
tcp://localhost:2947          NMEA0183>
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Time: n/a                      Lat: n/a               Lon: n/a                │
└───────────────────────────────── Cooked TPV ─────────────────────────────────┘
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ GPGSA GPGSV GPRMC GPGGA                                                      │
└───────────────────────────────── Sentences ──────────────────────────────────┘
┌──────────────────┐┌────────────────────────────┐┌────────────────────────────┐
│Ch PRN  Az El S/N ││Time:      065526.00        ││Time:      065526.00        │
│ 0   2  58 59   0 ││Latitude:     2328.2329 N   ││Latitude:  2328.2329        │
│ 1   4   1 58   0 ││Longitude:   12056.9328 E   ││Longitude: 12056.9328       │
│ 2  10 299 44   0 ││Speed:                      ││Altitude:                   │
│ 3  24  89 41   0 ││Course:                     ││Quality:   0   Sats: 00     │
│ 4  29  56 26  35 ││Status:    V       FAA: N   ││HDOP:      0.0              │
│ 5  18 269 25   0 ││MagVar:                     ││Geoid:                      │
│ 6  27 112 25   0 │└─────────── RMC ────────────┘└─────────── GGA ────────────┘
│ 7  31 160 15   0 │┌────────────────────────────┐┌────────────────────────────┐
│ 8  30 237  7   0 ││Mode: A1 Sats:              ││UTC:           RMS:         │
│ 9  25  43  3  33 ││DOP: H=      V=      P=     ││MAJ:           MIN:         │
│10  29 219 26  36 ││TOFF:                       ││ORI:           LAT:         │
│11                ││PPS:                        ││LON:           ALT:         │
└────── GSV ───────┘└──────── GSA + PPS ─────────┘└─────────── GST ────────────┘
```

Comment: See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145470/66509) for other receiver but same method.

Comment: @N0rbert Since it is showing data coming in I think I have that part working?

Comment: You are running it via TCP, but I tried using physical port address. Also you can try to move receiver out the building allowing it to see the open sky :)