# ubuntu 18 navit gpsd

Tags: gps

I have Ubuntu 18
I have a skytraq gps with pl2303 converter attached to ttyUSB0
I can't make gpsd work
I changed /etc/defaults/gpsd as:

```
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.

# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyUSB0"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

When I use xgps, no data, it does not work, so even navit does not work

Comment: Does `sudo gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0` works for you? Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145470/66509) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but hope not too late:
If the  pl2302 works on ttyUSB0
Check this

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The Different to your File is: `GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"`

Works on Ubuntu 18 ad 20

The example for my File with Navilock NL602 on `/dev/ttyACM0`
in commands `olt gps-mouse NL302 /dev/ttyUSB0`

```
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.
#hier liegt die Datei /etc/default/gpsd
# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"
# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="false"
# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
#neue GPS-Mouse Navilock NL602U
DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM0"
#alte GPS-MMouse Navilock NL302U
#DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```